# How to send object from c# client to java sever?

Tags: java, c#, serialization

Hello Im using java ServerSocketChannel and I'm trying to receive the object from a C# client.

If I'm trying to send `A`, do I need the same class structure in Java and C# like this?

**Java: A.java**

```
public class A extends Serialize{
String a;
}
```

**C#: A.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class A {
string a;
}
```

And finally - how can I send the data?

Comment: Send it as a json. This is what json is for and yes your model is correct (it should be same on both the ends)

Comment: You'll need to include exactly how the code is being executed, what form of serialization you're using in .NET, etc. The details you've provided simply aren't enough.

Comment: Maybe using `Socket.SenfFile` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2.aspx

Comment: you should to search about SOA, because you transfer an object from a language to another language how can understand each other?

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` may help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx